# Airflow scheduling old tasks after the DAG is unpaused

Tags: airflow

I paused a job DAG for one month. This job runs every 10 minutes. Now that I turned it on I can see airflow is trying to run everything since the day I paused the job.

Each time I am clearing the tasks list more tasks are getting scheduled. It will likely have 2000+ tasks.

I want the DAG to start the current tasks and discard all the tasks from the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `catchup` should solve your challenge, it is an argument of the [DAG](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/dag-run.html#catchup):

> An Airflow DAG with a start_date, possibly an end_date, and a schedule_interval defines a series of intervals which the scheduler turns into individual DAG Runs and executes. **The scheduler, by default, will kick off a DAG Run for any interval that has not been run since the last execution date (or has been cleared). This concept is called Catchup.**
> If your DAG is written to handle its catchup (i.e., not limited to the interval, but instead to Now for instance.), then you will want to turn catchup off. This can be done by setting catchup = False in DAG

```py
dag = DAG(
    'tutorial',
    default_args=default_args,
    start_date=datetime(2015, 12, 1),
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    catchup=False)
```

Comment: In Airflow 2.2, The catchup=False doesn't seem to work on enabling dags from paused state.  As soon as a dag in enabled it starts running the dag for all the dates from the last execution date instead of running from current date.

Comment: Where did you define the catchup? Could you post the DAG definition?

Comment: `dag = DAG(
    'catchup_trial',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='30 12 * * *',
    catchup=False)`

Comment: I have also raised a question for the same here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73074385/is-there-a-way-to-keep-the-next-dag-run-date-updated-even-for-a-paused-dag-in-ai